# Java - XML - Global Parsing

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I need some help , I would like from any XML file on input to have every parents nodes. 
I mean without to look in the xml file to see nodes names.

Of course , I use a parser but my problem is really in creating of a function which will do this work.

Actually, I just want to have the nodes names who has children.

Thank you guys :)

Comment: I for one would very much like to know how you intend on knowing information about the contents of an xml without having to read the file.  It would revolutionize computer programming.  Quantum xml parsing - you can use its contents if you don't care about the result of the processing.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to download an XML parsing library for Java, and look for a parameter for a node such as "children", or perhaps a function for counting the children of a node such as "countChildren" or "getChildren". Once you find this you can iterate over your nodes and make a note of the nodes that return 0/null children.

Comment: I tried this :
http://pastebin.com/2vXLbVHs

I don't understand what's wrong... It should display only nodes names wich are parents nodes